# How is Visual Studio's implicit referencing of TypeScript files supposed to work?

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I'm giving TypeScript another try at version 0.9.5, having left it alone for a while.

Amongst the mixture of new and old information I've found, I got the idea that all TypeScript files in a project will "implicitly reference" each other.

I can't work out what this means. One theory I have is that it means that every file will be able to see all the functions, classes, etc. exported from every other file, all at the global scope. (This doesn't exactly sound like a good idea, if it's true.)

The problem is, I can't be sure if any interpretation is correct, because there seem to be bugs in the 0.9.5 integration with Visual Studio so it isn't doing what (some) people expect.

My test is an 'HTML Application with TypeScript' project created in Visual Studio 2013 with the TypeScript addon installed from the link in the project template page.

I added a second `.ts` file that exports a class with a silly name:

```
export class Hedgehog {
    spikes() {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

and also added `knockout.d.ts` from [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped).

In the main `app.ts` file, VS gives me intellisense errors if I try to use my class from `app.ts`:

```
var h = new Hedgehog(); // Could not find symbol Hedgehog
```

It also complains if I try to use anything from `ko`:

```
var five = ko.observable(5); // Could not find symbol ko
```

[This issue complains that implicit referencing doesn't work](https://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/2071) and there is a comment hinting at the solution, which is to hand-edit the project file. However, that person changed this line of their project:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets"
        Condition="'$(Configuration)' == 'Debug'" />
```

To this:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" 
        Condition="Exists('$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
```

And then they were apparently happy (with what result though?!)

But my just-generated project *already* looks like the second version. I tried removing the condition altogether:

```
<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />
```

And then I get some progress. I now have intellisense for Knockout in both .ts files, but I still can't use my `Hedgehog` class. I need to add:

```
import otherFile = require('otherFile');
var Hedgehog = otherFile.Hedgehog;
```

This is actually ideal. In my main JavaScript project, already use commonjs modules with a home-grown linker (similar to [browserify](http://browserify.org/) or [webmake](https://github.com/medikoo/modules-webmake)) and so I definitely don't want all my thousands of exports to be merged into a giant global scope (I'm sincerely hoping that isn't the intended behaviour). But I also use 3rd party libraries like Knockout and jQuery, which I just mix into the global scope so they are available to all modules just like the DOM. So I want `.d.ts` to be treated differently and automatically add their declarations to the global scope for all modules.

So the end result of hand-hacking is that I have exactly the behaviour I want. But is it going to continue like that in TypeScript 1.0?

I read on the [announcement post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/12/05/announcing-typescript-0-9-5.aspx):

> With the previous improvements to the Visual Studio experience, we've
>   moved to projects implicitly referencing the .ts files contained in
>   the project.  This cut down on having to explicitly reference your
>   files in the project, bringing the experience much closer to C#. 
>   Unfortunately, it also did not work well when using the option to
>   concatenate your output .js file.
>
> We're continuing to improve this experience.  Starting with 0.9.5, you
>   can now add an _references.ts file to your project.  This file will be
>   the first passed to the compiler, allowing you more control over the
>   order the generated .js file when used in combination with the Combine
>   JavaScript output into file option (the equivalent of using the --out
>   commandline option).

I can't intuit anything from that! Are they saying they've changed the behaviour but *only* when combining JS output files? Or did they change it in all cases? If it helps, I have not enabled "Combine JavaScript output into file" option in my test project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All TypeScript files in a project do implicitly reference each other. This is basically like saying that they're all getting passed to the compiler together, as if you had specified all their names on the command line.

However, this only happens for files that have a `Build Action` (see the properties window) of `TypeScriptCompile`. For lame technical reasons, this is not the default when adding a .ts or .d.ts file to a project, so you'll need to manually change the `Build Action` property if you want the file to be included in the project context. This is why your file couldn't see `ko` implicitly.

The second issue is the use of `export`. For a full discussion see [Modules in TypeScript](http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Modules%20in%20TypeScript), but the short version is that when you use `export` at top-level, the containing file becomes an external module (as you discovered) and thus its contents are not automatically visible to other files without using an `import` (again as you discovered). This is the runtime behavior as well. If you want the object to go into the global scope, just leave off the `export` keyword - there is no notion *per se* of file-level visibility in TypeScript when you're not using external modules.

Finally, yes, you can mix and match whether you get third-party libraries like JQuery or Knockout through an external module import (`import ko = require('ko')`) or through the global scope (`$.whatever`) as long as their definition files are authored to support that, as `knockout.d.ts` is.

Comment: I'd already seen some discussion of the problem with the Build Action setting on a few blog posts, but oddly it doesn't seem to be a problem for me. I can create a new VS2013 TypeScript project, then use "Add existing item", add `knockout.d.ts`, and it is added with Build Action set to TypeScriptCompile.

Comment: I guess the strange behaviour I was seeing must be down to some install glitch or other (I had the TS add-on installed with 2012 already, then I installed 2013 on the same machine). The info in that wiki page is extremely useful. I wish it had been linked to from somewhere easy to find! :) It seems a little counter-intuitive that marking one declaration in a file as an `export` causes all the others to become less visible. But I'm glad there's a official way to get the mix of features I want.

Answer (score 1):

Just to respond to your comment:

> And then they were apparently happy (with what result though?!)

When I moved to using the Exists condition instead of the Debug one then I was once again the grateful recipient of intellisense. Essentially the TypeScript Language Service came back to life when I did this.

For what its worth I'm now happily using Knockout (with the global ko variable) in my project.

_references.TS no longer appears to be necessary unless you need to influence the overload ordering of functions available to you. (I don't think this is something that is an issue for you going by what you've said.)